# fancybox next prev or goTo

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Is there a way to swap images on fancybox (v2) galleries manually?

Something like:

`$.fancybox.next()`, `$.fancybox.prev()` or `$.fancybox.goto(idx)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're looking for the `$.fancybox.next()`, `$.fancybox.prev()` and `$.fancybox.jumpto()` methods.

From [Fancybox v2 Documentation](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs):

next :

> $.fancybox.next()
>
> Navigate to next gallery item prev

previous :

> $.fancybox.prev()
>
> Navigate to previous gallery item

jumpto :

> $.fancybox.jumpto( [index] )
>
> Navigate to gallery item by index. Item counting starts from 0, e.g. $.fancybox.jumpto( 0 ); will open the first, e.g. $.fancybox.jumpto( 1 ); will second, etc

Comment: `$.fancybox.next()` and `$.fancybox.prev()` are also valid API methods.

Comment: fancybox.jumpto() seems a little bugged... acts like jump()/next().